# Reference type field with derived display field

Tags: ng-admin

In ng-admin I am able to add a field of type `reference` and display the `name` of the referenced entity by

```
nga.field('schedule', 'reference')
  .targetEntity(schedule)
  .targetField(nga.field('name'))
  .label('Schedule'),
```

Is it possible to display a derived field of the referenced entity, say `name (id)`?

I tried using `.template()` with no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to use `map()`, as seen in the [Posters galore demo](https://github.com/marmelab/ng-admin-demo/blob/319466729aa7cc15bf0baa79ce8caf18ef99cef9/js/commands/config.js#L13):

```js
nga.field('schedule', 'reference')
  .targetEntity(schedule)
  .targetField(nga.field('name').map((v, e) => e.name + ' (' + e.id + ')'))
  .label('Schedule')
```