# Reference many fields [ng-admin]

Tags: ng-admin

I want to display two target fields in a reference-many

```
nga.field('pm', 'reference_many')
.targetEntity(worker)
.targetField(nga.field('name'))
    .filters(function(search) {
      if (!search) {
       return;
       }
     return {
       q: search
       }
     return search ? { q: search } : null;
      })
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: i don't understand..

Comment: You should use the `map()`, as explained in [this other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33906215/reference-type-field-with-derived-display-field).